# Reduce the number of lines of code

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is there any way to compress this code? What this does is after a period of 100ms the timer ticks and it posts the next letter. Is there a smaller code version of this?

I just want to make it type out text one character at a time.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right there?")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right there??";
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right there")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right there?";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right ther")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right there";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right the")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right ther";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right th")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right the";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right t")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right th";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right ")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right t";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You right")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right ";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You righ")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You right";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You rig")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You righ";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You ri")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You rig";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You r")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You ri";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You ")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You r";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... You")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You ";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... Yo")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... You";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... Y")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... Yo";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm... ")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... Y";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm...")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm... ";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm..")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm...";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm.")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm..";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hmm")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm.";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "Hm")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hmm";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "H")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Hm";
        }
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "H";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string fullText = "Hmm... You right there??";
int currentPos = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentPos++;
    textBox2.Text = fullText.Substring(0, currentPos);

    if (currentPos == fullText.Length)
        timer1.Stop();
}
```

*(Note, untested)*

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to write :)

Comment: Yeah its good it just pops up saying it can't find SubString :/

Comment: when it lets me tick your answer i will.

Answer (score 2):

```
string all = "Hmm... You right there??";
if (textBox1.Text.Length < all.Length)
    textBox1.Text += all[textBox1.Text.Length];
else
    timer1.Stop();
```

Comment: This just posts H over and over and over doesn't make it to the m?

Comment: @Terrii: No, it will add the next char that follows after the last in the TextBox (according to the full-string). Ideone doen't like Winforms, otherwise i would have demonstrated it.

Comment: Yeah i did that but its just spamming H every 100ms

Comment: @Terrii: Have you noticed that i've (mistakenly) used a different `TextBox` variable `textBox1`? Maybe you have copy/pasted my code and there's also a `textBox1` on your form.

Comment: yeah i noticed that and i changed it to the textbox i needed changed